# Unable to print a list of nested dict keys?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dict that looks something like so:

```
{'Tesco': [{'Parking': 'True', 'TrolleyHire': True,
  'Location': {'Address': {'BuildingName': 'Church Street',
             'BuildingNumber': '14', 'City' : 'London'}, 
  'Permit' = True},
```

Basically it is a dict, where the keys contain a nested dict in the form of a list.

I want to print out all nested keys within the first "Tesco" Key above.

I have tried:

```
for key in dict:
for key2 in dict[key]:
    print (key2.keys())
```

However I keep getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'.

key above contains the Tesco key and another key.

key2 above contains the list of dicts (key/value pairs) associated with the Tesco key.

key2.keys() should provide the list of keys associated with that dict but it doesn't seem to quite work!

I do not want a function to do this for me.

Apparently it is a very easy solution but I just can't figure it out.
I have literally spent 5 hours on it and I now officially give up as it seems like it should be extremely simple to do :(

Comment: What you posted is not a valid python dict. Please make an example that actually runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me:

```
dict = {
 'Tesco': [{'Parking': 'True', 'TrolleyHire': True,
 'Location': {'Address': {'BuildingName': 'Church Street',
 'BuildingNumber': '14', 'City' : 'London'}, 
 'Permit': True}}]
}

for key in dict:
    for key2 in dict[key]:
        print (key2.keys())
```

This prints:

```
dict_keys(['Location', 'Parking', 'TrolleyHire'])
```

Is that definitely the dictionary as you are using it? I had to add some stuff onto the end to complete it.

**EDIT: After seeing your original code.**

The JSON is creating a dict with two keys - Scheme and ChargeDevice - as you say. You iterate through each of these keys.

On the first pass then, `key` is equal to `"Scheme"`.

You then say `for key2 in data[key]`, which takes the dictionary associated with "Scheme" and iterates through its keys.

The problem is that key2 will always represent a key string - and strings don't have keys, only dicts do. For example, key2 will take on the value "SchemeCode", which is a string, and you are calling `key2.keys()` - and strings don't have a keys() method, hence the error. You probably just want `print(key2)`.

**Edit 2**

I'm not sure I entirely understand what you need, but the following will print a list of keys, without duplicates, in the second level of the main dict.

```
key_names = []
for key in data:
    for key2 in data[key]:
        if type(key2) == str and key2 not in key_names:
            key_names.append(key2)
        elif type(key2) == dict:
            for key3 in key2.keys():
                if key3 not in key_names:
                    key_names.append(key3)
print(key_names)
```

If you want to go arbitrarily deep, you will need to use a function that calls itself recursively I think.

Comment: Hmm I keep getting:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
on print (key2.keys())

Comment: The strange thing is that I am pretty sure this worked exactly as intended yesterday. Same dict, nothing has changed.

Comment: The dictionary you put in the question can't be the one you are using, as it is missing braces at the end, and has the wrong syntax. It might become clearer if you pasted the actual dictionary from your code.

Comment: The actual dict I am using comes from a json file which I have loaded onto a variable called data using json.loads
http://chargepoints.dft.gov.uk/api/retrieve/registry/format/json.
It has over 3000 lines which is why I can't post the full thing, just a snippet

Comment: Are you using the whole object represented in that JSON? I tried doing that and got `KeyError: 'Scheme'` - presumably you are using a subsection of it? Just trying to reproduce your original error :)

Comment: I ran Sam's code and it works for me. I downloaded the json file, modified the code a tiny bit to use the json file and got the error: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Comment: Yes mate, here is the code I used: 
http://pastebin.com/zmjUTfTh

Comment: Sam: I clicked on the link -> google chrome browser, did a "save page as"

Comment: Hmm strange it doesn't on my chrome. 
Did you try to copy the url and paste it directly into your address bar?

Comment: Then I did a cut/paste of the file from notepad to JSONlint.com (8.5 GB) and it says the json is valid.

Comment: The link and the text are the same except the link has "http://" in the front. I put the link in Chrome addr bar and it goes to the same file. I also did a file compare on the downloaded file and the cut and paste file, they were the same.

Comment: Sam: changing the print statement to "print key2" gives me a 9MB output file. Can you update the code in your answer.

Comment: OK, I have updated. The problem is essentially that the keys are a mix of str objects and dict objects.

Comment: I like it !  I changed 'data' to 'dict' in two lines and 'str' to 'unicode' and I get the expected result of `[u'SchemeCode', u'SchemeData']` I'm not sure why I'm seeing unicode though.

Comment: In Python 2, the json library makes all text unicode regardless of what the source was. It can be quite annoying to be honest, though I don't use Python 2 much.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Makes so much sense now!

Answer (score 1):

It is probably more elegant to just use .values():

```
for sub_list in dict.values():
    for sub_dict in sub_list:
        print(sub_dict.keys())
```

Comment: Still getting:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys' on last line

Comment: Can you please update your question with the actual dictionary used? This works fine for me

Comment: See my comment for Sam about what I did. I get the same error when using tobspr's code.